# Salesforce Code Coverage for Batch Class - not running execute function

Tags: apex, unit-test, batch, code-coverage, account

I wrote these test class for a batch class and for some reason I cannot get it to run the execute function when running the batch class. I am only getting 28% coverage. Any ideas?

Batch class:

```
global class BoxUpdateAccountsBatch implements Database.Batchable<sObject>, Database.AllowsCallouts {
//Start 
global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC){
    // query all accounts without docusign folder
    string query = 'SELECT Id, docusignBoxFolderId__c, uploadedBoxFolderId__c FROM Account WHERE docusignBoxFolderId__c = null OR uploadedBoxFolderId__c = null';
    system.debug('query::'+query);
    return Database.getQueryLocator(query);
}

//Execute
   global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC,List<Account> scope){
       System.debug('SCOPE::' + scope);
       box.Toolkit boxToolkit = new box.Toolkit();
       List<Account> accounts = new List<Account>();
       
       // create folders for exisiting accounts
       for (Account a : scope) {
           BoxBatchMethods.updateExistingAccountFolders(a, boxToolkit);
           accounts.add(a);
       }

       boxToolkit.commitChanges();
       
       // update salesforce record
       try {
            System.debug('scope::'+scope);
            update scope;
       } catch(exception e){
            System.debug('BoxUpdateAccountsBatch exception:' + e.getMessage());
       } 
   }

   //Finish
   global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC){
       System.debug('All Accounts Processed.');
   }}
```

BoxBatchMethods class:

```
public static void updateExistingAccountFolders(Account a, box.Toolkit boxToolkit) {
    
    // create account folder
    String accountFolderId = boxToolkit.createFolderforRecordId(a.Id, null, true);
    
    // update account docusign folder
    if (a.docusignBoxFolderId__c == null) {
        String docusignFolderId = boxToolkit.createFolder('Folder 1', accountFolderId, null);
        a.docusignBoxFolderId__c = docusignFolderId;
    }
    
    // update account uploaded folder 
    if (a.uploadedBoxFolderId__c == null) {
        String uploadedFolderId = boxToolkit.createFolder('Folder 2', accountFolderId, null);
        a.uploadedBoxFolderId__c = uploadedFolderId;
    }
}
```

Test class:

```
@isTest
public class BoxBatchTests {    
static testMethod void accountsBatchTest() 
    {
        
        for (Integer i=0; i<200; i ++) {
            Account acc = new Account();
            acc.Name = 'testaccount' + i;
            Id businessApplicantId = MSUtility.getRecordTypeIdByName('Business Applicant');
            acc.RecordTypeId = businessApplicantId;
            acc.docusignBoxFolderId__c = null;
            acc.uploadedBoxFolderId__c = null;
            insert acc;
        }

        Test.startTest(); 
            BoxUpdateAccountsBatch a = new BoxUpdateAccountsBatch();
            Database.executeBatch(a);    
        Test.stopTest();
    }}
```

Thanks for any help!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There can be few reason. There might be some trigger/flow that is populating those two fields on insert of account.

Debug account after insert and see those field are populated or null. If not null, update those field to null or you can stop the trigger in your test class.

If it is not null then upto which line you are getting coverage in execute method?

Comment: Thank you so much! The suggested to not run the triggers in my test classes worked. I followed the answer on this question: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/63634/prevent-trigger-from-running-in-single-test#:~:text=Then%20in%20your%20Test%20Class,the%20trigger%20won't%20run!

Answer (score 0):

You have made a basic mistake error in your test class. In test classes we have to create your own data to test the code of main class.

In your test class you are initialising an Account record but you are not inserting it. Hence, effectively your start method in the batch class is returning no records and hence coverage is low.

Please add `insert acc;` in your test class.

However according to test class best practices you should insert account in bulk to test your batch class.

Comment: Thank you for your response! That is my mistake in writing my code in the question. I have updated it above and facing the same error.

Comment: I did notice, if instead of inserting the account in the for loop and instead add the accounts to a list and insert the list after the for loop, I get an error saying the accounts were already inserted.